# string % 4 -> what is that in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In ruby `%` is used to format string.

```
str % arg → new_str
```

However I do not get

```
number = '/javascripts/cache/money.js'.bytes.sum % 4
```

in this commit https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f6a6b51ae551b7f936e974cba3ad4b30422d6804

Comment: It acts like `sprintf` or `mod`, depending on the first argument. Your first example shows a String, while the second example shows an Integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this % is Integer modulo.

```
'/javascripts/cache/money.js'.bytes  returns an Enumerator

'/javascripts/cache/money.js'.bytes.sum   returns an Integer

'/javascripts/cache/money.js'.bytes.sum % 4   returns an Integer
```

They may have defined the sum method themselves, which may be the reason for the question?

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the class of the object.

On a string, `%` behaves like so:

```
"Hello, %s" % ['world'] #=> "Hello, world"
```

Note that in Ruby 1.9.2, you can add names:

```
"Hello, %{name}" % {:name => "Nick"} #=> "Hello, Nick"
```

For more details, see the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001127).

However, on an integer, it is the modulo function. See the [Fixnum docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Fixnum.html#M001084) and the [Numeric docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Numeric.html#M000968).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually just the sum of all bytes in the string, modulo 4.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sum returns a sum of numbers in an array, you're doing `number % number` here, not `str % arg`.

Answer (score 1):

```
number = '/javascripts/cache/money.js'.bytes.sum % 4
```

is

```
int % int -> int
```

which is modulo method

http://apidock.com/ruby/Bignum/%25